# Android WebRTC crashes during the second time I run the WebRTC Activity

Tags: android, webrtc

I am making an app that you can video call through WebRTC.
On the first call to the Activity for WebRTC, everything runs smoothly, but on the second time, I get crashes due to Null Pointer exception on my localPeer object:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void org.webrtc.PeerConnection.setRemoteDescription(org.webrtc.SdpObserver, org.webrtc.SessionDescription)' on a null object reference
```

Before finishing the activity, I have tried clearing up the resources onDestroy as such :

```
  if (localPeer != null) {
            localPeer.close();
            localPeer.dispose();
        }
```

Am I doing anything wrong to clear up the resources that may cause the crash? Or what causes `peerConnectionFactory.createPeerConnection()` to return null?

Comment: Check out my this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51074131/webrtc-native-crashed-when-i-call-peerconnection-close/51077216#51077216 It might be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I found the problem for this.

I have a Client class that acts as a wrapper for my Socket.IO connections. Let's call it ClientClass. Within the ClientClass I have a private static ClientClass instance that can only be accessed through calling the class's static getInstance() method.

During the closing of the connection I forgot to set it to null as such:

```
  public void close() {
    socket.emit("bye");
    socket.off();
    socket.disconnect();
    socket.close();
    roomName = null;
    socket = null;
    instance = null; //I forgot this line
}
```

It's a pretty weird issue that is tricky to debug from the errors, unable to be traced by just reading the error logs.